# How to reload config.yml file on command in Bukkit Plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I was trying to reload `config.yml` file on command with `Bukkit Plugin`, I don't know how to do it.

I searched on google and I found one answer, but when I used it, `config.yml` was not generating. Here's my code:

[BlockChanger](https://github.com/Maxisy/BlockChanger/tree/master/src)

Please help

Comment: Could you please add a short and relevant snippet here? I don't think many people will click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the final modifier from your config variables, else this can't refresh from config file.

Then you need a method for reload the config and set the config variables again. An example based on your code:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {

    loadConfig(this);
}

private final String prefix = ChatColor.AQUA + "[";

private String prefixTrue;
private String prefixFalse;

public void loadConfig(Plugin plugin) {
    File file = new File(plugin.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/config.yml");
    FileConfiguration cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    prefixTrue = prefix + cfg.getString("prefix") + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " ";
    prefixFalse = prefix + cfg.getString("prefix") + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " ";
}
```

Make sure that you call the method `loadConfig` in `onEnable` and every time you want to reload the config

Comment: And should I leave `getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);` and `saveConfig();` in `onEnable()`?

Comment: `copyDefaults(true)` can be helpful to create first time a config file with default values. The documentation can be found [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/file/FileConfigurationOptions.html#copyDefaults-boolean-).

Comment: OK, i got it. Thanks!